# Custom Action running as 64-bit on 32-bit install

Tags: wix

This application is a plugin for a larger application. To complete our installation, we need to run a batch script provided by the main application. The batch script errors saying that a certain registry key doesn't exist, but it exists in the WOW6432 part of the registry. It appears that the custom action is being ran as 64-bit, attempting to fetch the registry without the WOW6432. I have no access or control of the batch file, so I can't change that to check both parts of the registry.

How can I make sure the custom action is ran as 32-bit?

The cmd process is running in 64-bit mode when the batch file is ran.

**Edit**: To check if it is running 64 vs 32, I created a seperate batch script which checks looks for a registry key in HKLM/Software/SomeKey. The key is actually located in HKLM/Software/Wow6432/SomeKey. Manually running it with %windir%\SysWow64\cmd.exe (task manager flags this process as *32) works fine. Running it with the regular cmd.exe it cannot find the registry key. Putting this same batch file as a custom action in wix results in the non-*32 cmd to open and the regkey search failure.

I set this batch in Wix like this:

```
<CustomAction Id="batchCA" Property="BATCHFILE" ExeCommand="" Execute="deferred" />
```

Where BATCHFILE is a property set the the batchfile path. i.e "C:\temp\batch.cmd". It seems to run fine, but am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Since Windows Installer doesn't support batch file custom actions directly, it might help if you indicate how you configured this to run, and what makes you believe it's running as 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should explicitly specify the command-line exe to be 32bit. So instead of directly calling your batch like "yourScriptName.cmd", you should use this:

```
%windir%\SysWoW64\cmd.exe /c yourScriptName.cmd
```

Comment: But that will go unresolved on 32-bit systems. Is there a way find the cmd.exe that will be resolved regardless of bitness?

Comment: I'm afraid no when you need non-default path to cmd.exe on x64 machine. You should create 2 custom actions then and configure conditions when to launch each of them

Comment: Or just reference [SystemFolder] in the custom action. That's always the 32-bit folder (aka SysWow64 on 64-bit systems): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372055.aspx